# mac cntlm error - invalid proxy configuration file

Tags: macos, proxy

When I run the below command

```
cntlm -v
```

I am getting below error.

```
Mar  2 11:25:21  cntlm[39244] <Error>: Could not open default config file
Mar  2 11:25:21  cntlm[39244] <Error>: Parent proxy address missing.
Exitting with error. Check daemon logs or run with -v.
```

When I try with following command

```
cntlm -v /usr/etc/cntlm.conf
```

Getting below error

```
Mar  2 11:25:35  cntlm[39246] <Error>: Invalid proxy specification /usr/etc/cntlm.conf.
Exitting with error. Check daemon logs or run with -v.
```

Can anybody give me suggestion to fix this

I am running cntlm on mac os - 10.11.3

Answer (score 1):

Please check if you correctrly setup you proxy setting in the cntml.ini file.

i have lost port while specifigy the  proxy address like this:

192.168.78.78 but it has to be like

```
Proxy 192.23.232.23:port
```

Answer (score 0):

To specify a configuration file, you need to use -c

```
cntlm -v -c /usr/etc/cntlm.conf
```